# Duplicate SQL Schema in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-schema

I have a requirement that a user can have multiple environments to make experiments and test how good their modifications are; after the users are satisfied with the modifications they've done to the data in the working environment, these modifications can be (partially or completely) copied to another environment; these environments can be created as empty or as copies of other environments; right now we are using SQL Azure and our current (not implemented) approach is creating each environment as a different SQL schema in the same database using the statement

```
CREATE SCHEMA
```

till now in POCs this is working really good for us. But what i don't like of this approach is that creating a new schema involves executing several scripts to create the tables and the SPs in the new schema, so as we create or update the default schema objects, we also need to update the scripts that create the schema, also that when the schema is created we need to bulk copy the data from the original schema using another script, so considering the size of the client's data this process sometimes it cannot be not as fast as I would like, and also maintaining the SQL code to create environments is not that good for the team.

so my question is, is there any way to duplicate an entire dbo schema with a different name using T-SQL Statements?, i know this can be done manually using SQL Server Management Studio and the generate scripts option, but this must happen automatically because the users can create a new environment at any time, i already checked the documentation for

```
ALTER SCHEMA TargetSchema 
TRANSFER SourceSchema.TableName;
```

but this just changes the database object schema, it does not create an actual copy of the object.

EDIT:
I am not trying to create different databases for dev, qa and production, I  already have them; what I want to achieve is create a web app with multiple environments, each environment is a sandbox for the final user to make experiments, imagine it is like creating a draft before making this data available for the general public, so when the users are satisfied with the modifications they can move this data to the public environment and then when it is moved, it is available for others to see it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CREATE DATABASE ... AS COPY OF transact-sql statement to create copies of your Production database that can be used as QA, testing and development databases.

```
CREATE DATABASE db_copy   
    AS COPY OF ozabzw7545.db_original ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'P2') ;
```

Here ozabzw7545 is the name of Azure SQL Database server.

Comment: we tried creating a full copy of the database, but the process is even more slow than creating a single schema with every database object, also i am not trying to create databases for dev, qa and production i already have them; what we want to achieve is create a web app with multiple environments, each environment is like a sandbox for the final user to make experiments, it is like creating a draft before making this data available for the general public

Comment: What about deploying a dacpac. https://vijayt.com/post/deploying-a-data-tier-application-in-sql-azure-programatically/

Answer (score 0):

The following is the full syntax + additional information that is specific to Azure SQL database: [CREATE DATABASE (Azure SQL Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-azure-sql-database)

Additional Information for [Copy an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy)

You also can use PowerShell:

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
-ServerName $sourceserver `
-DatabaseName "MySampleDatabase" `
-CopyResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
-CopyServerName $targetserver `
-CopyDatabaseName "CopyOfMySampleDatabase"
```

Comment: I tried creating a full copy of the database, but the process is even more slow than creating a single schema with every database object